# AIR app:How to load swf from server

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

My app structure is below:

```
(local)
Login.swf
(server)
Main.swf
assets1.swf
assets2.swf

Login.swf -> Main.swf (OK!)
Main.swf -> assets1&2.swf (fail!, downloaded but not trigger complete event)
-progress event: bytes:loaded==total
```

Why?
How can i load assets from server using Main.swf?
I found somebody say it is crossdomain problem...then how to solve?

```
var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.allowCodeImport = true;

_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete_handler);
_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loader_progress_handler);
_loader.loadBytes(_urlloader.data,context);
```

Thanks!

Comment: AIR for desktop? If mobile it's a complicated system on Ios and simpler in Android.

Comment: For corssdomain.xml Write following in crossdomain.xml file 
`<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>` And put that file in root folder.

Answer (score 0):

**BE AWARE:**

On mobile it only works on Android... iOS due to a security policy does not permit to load an swf inside another one.

Said that you can surerly load an SWF.

First of all we need to understand if you can download the SWF bytearray using the URLLoader.

if yes you can load the swf in a two step routine..

hope this help :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"               
                       showStatusBar="false"
                       creationComplete="downloadSwf()">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.SystemManager;

            import spark.components.Application;

            private function downloadSwf():void {
                // load the file with URLLoader into a bytearray
                sfwLoader.visible = false;                                                      

                var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

                // binary format since it a SWF
                loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
                loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoaded);
                loader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cantConnect);
                //load the file             
                loader.load(new URLRequest("url"));
            }

            private function cantConnect(e:IOErrorEvent):void
            {               
                var loader:URLLoader=URLLoader(e.target);
                loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoaded);
                loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cantConnect);
                // error handling   
                return;
            }

            private function onSWFLoaded(e:Event):void {
                // remove the event
                var loader:URLLoader=URLLoader(e.target);
                loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoaded);
                loader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, cantConnect);

                // add an Application context and allow bytecode execution 
                var context:LoaderContext=new LoaderContext();
                context.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution=true;

                // set the new context on SWFLoader
                sfwLoader.loaderContext = context;

                sfwLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

                // load the data from the bytearray
                sfwLoader.load(loader.data);
            }

            // your load complete function
            private function loadComplete(completeEvent:Event):void {
                sfwLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

                var swfApplication:* = completeEvent.target.content;

                var sysmgr:SystemManager = (swfApplication as SystemManager);
                sysmgr.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, swfAppComplete); 

            }

            private function swfAppComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
                sfwLoader.visible = true;
                var sysmgr:SystemManager = (event.currentTarget as SystemManager);
                sysmgr.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, swfAppComplete);
                var swfApp:Application = (sysmgr.application as Application);               
                if (!swfApp.hasOwnProperty("version")) {
                    return;                 
                }
                // version is a public property in the main of the loaded application
                var verion:String = swfApp["version"];          
                swfApp.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, appClose);
            }

            private function appClose(e:Event):void
            {
                sfwLoader.unloadAndStop(true);
                NativeApplication.nativeApplication.exit();
            }

            private function closeApp(e:CloseEvent):void
            {
                try{
                    (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication as WindowedApplication).close();   
                }
                catch(e:Error){}                
            }           
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>    
    <mx:SWFLoader id="sfwLoader" 
                  width="100%" visible="false"
                  height="100%"/>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```